# Почему в результате запроса ничего нет?

Tags: c#, xamarin

Разбирал пример, ссылка ниже:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dn879698.aspx

Скопировал запрос в браузерную строку строку, но подставил значение ZIP код как в примере 98052. Результат запроса получил:
{"query":{"count":1,"created":"2018-03-02T13:42:05Z","lang":"ru-RU","results":{"channel":{"units":{"distance":"mi","pressure":"in","speed":"mph","temperature":"F"}}}}}

По сути, он отработал, но ничего мне не вернул. Пробовал и другие индексы - ничего не получилось. В чем причина, можете подсказать?

Comment: думаю API просто не работает. это  GET запрос. можете в браузере попытаться разные ссылки попробовать. хотите пример - ищите рабочие API

Comment: как-то странно, авторитетный сайт и примеры недопилены до конца. API работает некорректно, но хоть что-то возвращает. Спасибо.

Comment: там пример за 2015 год. что вы хотите? :-)

Comment: Поддержка сайта и актуальность примеров- это отдельная тема.